# Pytest and virtualenv || Failed to configure container: [Errno 1]

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am currently working on a python program for finding flaky tests by running them multiple times. To achieve this goal, I'm executing the tests in a virtualenv in random order using pytest.

When I execute the program on a remote machine via slurm job, I get following error codes:

```
2019-11-26 18:18:18,642 - CRITICAL - Failed to configure container: [Errno 1] Creating overlay mount for '/' failed: Operation not permitted. Please use other directory modes, for example '--read-only-dir /'.

2019-11-26 18:18:18,777 - CRITICAL - Cannot execute 'pytest': execution in container failed.
```

This doesn't happen on my local machine, only on the task startet via the slurm job.

This is my first time working with python at this complexity, so I'm not really sure where to start solving the problem.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The problem has nothing with Python. You have errors in containter/cluster config.

Comment: I've tried contacting the admin to help me solve this problem, but he is currently not available. Is there anything I can do/configure myself to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that the problem only occurs on the newest version of **benchexec**.

When my python program executes *run exec --no-container --pytest* inside a virtualenv and benchexec is version 2.0 or higher, the error message displayed in my original post shows up. I simply tell pip to install an older version of benchexec in my virtualenv and voila it works.

I would've created the tag *benchexec* but don't have the necessary credit points for doing so. Feel free to do it for me!